# Bias-T circuit design

Tags: rf

I am looking to design a bias-T wide band circuit for 10-2000MHz.

I know how to calculate the cutoff frequency at 2GHz and can also find the value of the inductor to be used using the following formula.

- How do I calculate the lower cutoff at 10MHz in the same circuit, basically looking at wideband?
- Any ideas if my calculation is correct?
- Do I need to use only 1 capacitor or can it be a combination of multiple for fine tuning?

Xc = 1/2*pi*f*C; C=1/(2*pi*f*Xc)
C = 1 / (2 * 3.14 * 2000MHz * 2Ohms) = 80pF

Xl = 2*pi*f*L;  L = Xl / (2 * pi * f)
L = 20,000 Ohms / (2 * 3.14 * 2000MHz) = 1.5uH

Answer (score 2):

> C = 1 / (2 * 3.14 * 2000MHz * 2Ohms) = 80pF

This calculation gives you a capacitive reactance of 2 ohms at 2000 MHz, and proportionally increasing reactance at any frequency below 2000 MHz. That is, it will give you 4 ohms at 1000 MHz, 40 ohms at 100 MHz, and 400 ohms at 10 MHz. But what you want is to have very low capacitive reactance throughout the pass-band of the bias tee.

So you should choose the capacitor to have a low reactance at your lower band edge, and then it will have even lower reactance throughout the operating band. You might choose to make it 50 ohms (for 3 dB insertion loss in a 50 ohm system) at 10 MHz or some lower value (but that will move your 3-dB "cut-off" frequency below the 10 MHz you specified.

You will of course also have to make sure that the inductive parasitic behavior of your capacitor does not produce too much inductive reactance at the upper end of your frequency band.

Comment: ● 10-2000MHz bandwidth
● <1dB insertion loss across range
● Upto 30dBm RF power
● 25V max DC
● Operation in a 50ohm system


this is my requirement, what i am confused with for cutoff frequency capacitor should i chose the lowest range or highest and same for the inductor? to fond the correct values?  I mean in the formula, should i use 10Mhz or 2000Mhz for both, that is my confusion right.

Comment: @anatal, the capacitor and inductor nominal values determine the low-frequency cut-off. Parasitics generally determine the high frequency limit. Choosing parts (or combinations of parts) to manage the parasitics is the art of bias tee design.